# LWC locale does not match Apex version

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, user-record, locale

When I utilize the following in my LWC component:

```
import USER_LOCALE from '@salesforce/i18n/locale';
```

I get this back:  **en-US**

However, when I run the following in Apex:

```
UserInfo.getLanguage()
```

I get this:  **en_US**

Why does the LWC version of locale use a dash and not an underscore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the LWC version of locale use a dash and not an underscore?

Because this conforms to various standards set forth in RFCs, IETF specifications, etc. In reality, the problem here is Apex, which conforms to Java's implementation, which is considered non-standard by comparison. At this point, though, it's too late to change it in Apex without breaking all kinds of code that depend on the underscore. This goes back to the day when there was a [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) class, where you'd have static variables such as `Locale.en_US` (you can't use `-` in an identifier).

Comment: Makes sense, but I still find it odd that SF would conflict with itself.  Was this done because 'en-US' will recognized by other JavaScript APIs or browser extensions?

Comment: @MichaelSobczak Exactly. Apex was designed to conform to Java, LWC was designed to conform to standard JavaScript and browser support. These two methods of getting the locale are also temporally separated by about a decade, and things change to tend a lot in that amount of time.